# Why is database time value different from the value created in the ruby time object?

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in my seeds.rb file:

```
# create a 7 day wall
for day in 1..7
    # create the days
    d = Day.create(day: day)
    # for each day create the time slots. Use 15 minute timeslots for now
    start_time = Time.new.beginning_of_day
    puts start_time
    end_time = start_time.end_of_day
    puts end_time
    begin
            d.time_slots << TimeSlot.create(time: start_time)
            start_time += 15.minutes
            puts start_time
    end while start_time <= end_time
            puts "Start time after exit: #{start_time}"

    campaign.days << d
end
```

It creates right output as one would expect

```
2013-04-19 00:00:00 -0700
2013-04-19 23:59:59 -0700
2013-04-19 00:15:00 -0700
2013-04-19 00:30:00 -0700
2013-04-19 00:45:00 -0700
2013-04-19 01:00:00 -0700
2013-04-19 01:15:00 -0700
2013-04-19 01:30:00 -0700
2013-04-19 01:45:00 -0700
2013-04-19 02:00:00 -0700
2013-04-19 02:15:00 -0700
2013-04-19 02:30:00 -0700
2013-04-19 02:45:00 -0700
2013-04-19 03:00:00 -0700
2013-04-19 03:15:00 -0700
2013-04-19 03:30:00 -0700
....
```

When I look in the my db using sqlite browser, I see this too. When use my rails console to inspect the database I see:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > TimeSlot.find(1)
  TimeSlot Load (17.3ms)  SELECT "time_slots".* FROM "time_slots" WHERE "time_slots"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<TimeSlot id: 1, time: "2000-01-01 07:00:00", created_at: "2013-04-19 21:56:58", updated_at: "2013-04-19 21:56:58", campaign_id: nil, day_id: 1>
```

Why is the record in the database showing the wrong date? The timestamps are right, but the time field is wrong. I don't get it.

Comment: are you storing it as a `time` column or a `datetime` column in your database? if it's the first case i believe this could help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760963/time-fields-in-rails-coming-back-blank

Comment: Yes, I am using `time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on in this problem:

1. There is some nuance to using `time` and `datetime` types in rails. See [Time fields in Rails coming back blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760963/time-fields-in-rails-coming-back-blank)
2. The time zone is an issue. The db stores times in UTC/GMT. When `Time.new` is called it uses the system's current timezone.

The code to increment the time object is right. I just need to take the timezone into account when I'm displaying the times.